# Categorization of Mono, Epis in a Category

Tags: soft-question, category-theory

Let $C$ be a category. Then the following implications on [variants for monos](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monomorphism#variations) hold:

Iso $\implies$ SplitMono $\implies$ RegMono $\implies$ StrongMono $\implies$ ExtMono $\implies$ Mono,

And dually for Epi.

I have a good grasp of what Iso, SplitMono, RegMono and Mono are. I think of Iso as "essentially equal", SplitMono as a "subobject whose complement can be retracted", RegMono as a "subobject which can be equalized by 2 arrows", and Mono as just a "subobject".

Are there similar characterizations of the other monos, i.e., simple statements of the form such as "Strong Mono is a subobject such that ~"?

Comment: I don't think it is appropriate to refer to monomorphisms as subobjects. (Think about the example of topological spaces.) The notion of subobject is more accurately captured by extremal monomorphisms.